# Adding DocumentCompletedEvent in Awesomium webcontrol

Tags: .net, vb.net, awesomium

I am new with the Awesomium webcontrol. As I add the event DocumentCompleted for my webbrowser control same as i want to add for my Awesomium webcontrol how can i do that?

```
 AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New  _
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that event isn't as straight forward as .net's web control...but its effect can still be achieved. Here's how I usually do it, it looks a bit excessive for such a basic event, but I'll explain why it's all necessary. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub WebControl1_LoadingFrameComplete(sender As Object, e As Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs) Handles WebControl1.LoadingFrameComplete
    If e.IsMainFrame AndAlso Not WebControl1.IsNavigating AndAlso Not WebControl1.IsLoading Then
        'do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

OnLoadingFrameComplete is the closest Awesomium has to DocumentCompleted, but that alone doesn't indicate all the page's resources are finished loading. It can fire multiple times when individual frames/sub-frames are finished loading, that's why we check e.IsMainFrame because that is *usually* the last frame to load...that is how Awesomium's developers recommend detecting the page is finished loading. However, I've even had that fail on me a few times in the past, so I've added the Not IsLoading and Not IsNavigating which will prevent the sub's logic from being executed if there's still any kind of loading going on in the background. With those couple of checks added to the event, it has performed correctly and consistently for me so far.